# HTML CSS - How to create a <div> into another <div> , or how to insert a text into a <div>

Tags: html, css

```css
.myDiv2 {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv2">
  <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
    <h2 style="color: orange;"><b>I love you most</b></h2>
    <h2>Yes, of course:<b>I still love you</b></h2>
    <h2>Open Feeling</h2>
  </div>
```

See here how it looks, but I want the text to be place inside the div, not outside it.

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The actual issue you have is with the CSS:
`.myDiv2 { border: 2px solid yellow; height: 10px; margin-top: 80px; }`

You declare a definite height of `height: 10px;`. This is to small to contain the child div and as such an overflow of the parent div happend. Remove the height css-line and it will work smoothly.

```css
.myDiv2 {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv2">
  <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
    <h2 style="color: orange;"><b>I love you most</b></h2>
    <h2>Yes, of course:<b>I still love you</b></h2>
    <h2>Open Feeling</h2>
  </div>
</div> <!-- This needs to be closed but not causing the issue-->
```

Last but not least, you still need to close the last div, however it is not causing the issue.